# cUrl send a request with a json with file as a json key value

Tags: python, curl

This is my python code snippet that I am trying to convert to a single CURL request

```
with open(<filepath>, "rb") as f:
    my_image= base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")

my_session.post(url=<my_host>,json={"key1": {"key2": my_image}})
```

I understand --data-binary can be used to read a file, I am not sure how to send a CURL request with this payload and the image encoded/decoded in this manner

Comment: Can you share your attempts?

Comment: I was trying something similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/650391/send-base64-encoded-image-using-curl but the single quotes are not making sense to me

Answer (score 0):

*I am not sure how to send a CURL request with this payload and the image encoded/decoded in this manner*

Whole point of base64 ([RFC 3548](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3548/)) is

> Base encoding of data is used in many situations to store or transfer
> data in environments that, perhaps for legacy reasons, are restricted
> to only US-ASCII data.

In order to do that base64 *encoder* does turn any sequence of bytes (often file) into string having solely ASCII characters and when you use base64 *decoder* it turn that string back into original sequence of bytes.

Here

```
with open(<filepath>, "rb") as f:
    my_image= base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode("utf-8")

my_session.post(url=<my_host>,json={"key1": {"key2": my_image}})
```

you first encode file using base64 encoder and then send JSON with one value being text you got.

I do not know `curl` enough to say if it does or does not have ability to base64-encode, but if it last you would need separate tool for that.